# Unity does not package the plugin jar files along with the APK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, jar

I have an Android Unity project (I am using Unity 4.7.2f) which has a few Android plugin jar including Google Play Services, `Facebook` jar and `MoPub` jars. The APK compiles fine, but it fails to bundle any of the jars that are not directly in the `Assets/Plugins/Android` directory.

For example:

The `Facebook` jar is in `Assets/Plugins/Android/facebook/libs/facebooksdk.jar` and it does not get bundled with the APK, whereas, I have a `MoPub` jar that is in `Assets/Plugins/Android/mopub-volley-1.1.0.jar` which gets bundled properly.

If I move `facebooksdk.jar` to be under `Assets/Plugins/Android/` then it gets bundled properly. Anyone know why this is happening?

The project.properties file has

```
android.library=true
```

Answer (score 0):

> Once built, the shared library should be copied to the Assets->Plugins->Android folder

Nothing is said in documentation, that you can put `.jar` files in subfolder of `Android` folder. The only processed subfolder is `libs` for native `.so` libraries.

[Building Plugins for Android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html)

Comment: That's what I thought too, but here is the twist. This problem does not happen on my personal computer. It only happens on our build machine. On my PC, the jars are in nested folders